# jQuery .change() function must Fire only once

Tags: jquery, html

At my page I have a `<select>` tag named `#boxID`. next to it is a div named "wholeThingBody" that is hidden via jQuery.

```
<select id='boxID'>
  <option value='option1'> option1</option>
  <option value='option2'> option2</option> 
</select>

<div id='wholeThingBody'>
     Some content to permanently display once .change has been fired once
</div>
```

What I need is to have the user click on the `<select>` just once to show the hidden `<DIV>` the problem though is that when the user selects another option in the select, the DIV hides again. (it sort of toggles)

How can I make it so that when the user fires `.change` only once? I tried changing the ID but it doesn't work

```
$("#boxID").change(function () { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300); //show the content of div #wholeThingBody
        $(this).id = "okna"; //attempt to prevent wholeThingBody from toggle hiding
     });
    $("#wholeThingBody").hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use `slideDown` *(the best way)*:

   ```
   $("#boxID").change(function () { 
       $(this).next().slideDown(300);
   });
   $("#wholeThingBody").hide();
   ```
2. Remove listener:

   ```
   $("#boxID").on('change', function() {
       $(this).next().toggleSlide(300);
       $("#boxID").off('change');
   });
   $("#wholeThingBody").hide();
   ```
3. As for me, I would do this with CSS classes.

   CSS:

   ```
   #wholeThingBody {
       display: none;
   }

   #wholeThingBody.active { 
       display: block;
   }
   ```

   JS:

   ```
   $("#boxID").on('change', function() {
       $(this).next().addClass('active'); // It will add a class only once
   });
   ```

*By the way*, for the future, if you want to change the ID of a DOM element, then do this

```
this.id = "okna";
```

instead of

```
$(this).id = "okna";
```

Because `id` is a property of DOM-element, not jQuery-property

Comment: A complete answer. Accepted for it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 //var to remember if its fired before.
 var fired = false;
 $("#boxID").change(function () { 
      if(!fired){
         $(this).next().slideToggle(300); //show the content of div #wholeThingBody
         $(this).id = "okna"; 
         fired = true;
    }
 });
$("#wholeThingBody").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/) to register a handler which will be triggered only once, also since you want to display the element, instead of using [slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) use [slideDown()](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) like

```js
$("#boxID").one('change', function() {
  $(this).next().slideDown(300); //show the content of div #wholeThingBody
});
$("#wholeThingBody").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='boxID'>
  <option value='option1'>option1</option>
  <option value='option2'>option2</option>
</select>

<div id='wholeThingBody'>
  Some content to permanently display once .change has been fired once
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use slideDown instead of slideToggle

```
$("#boxID").change(function () { 
    $(this).next().slideDown(300);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `$.Callbacks("once")` , `callbacks.fireWith()`

```js
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");
var fn = function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(300); //show the content of div #wholeThingBody
};
callbacks.add(fn);
$("#boxID").change(function() {
  callbacks.fireWith(this);
});
$("#wholeThingBody").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='boxID'>
  <option value='option1'>option1</option>
  <option value='option2'>option2</option>
</select>

<div id='wholeThingBody'>
  Some content to permanently display once .change has been fired once
</div>
```